# Using Weak Event in .NetCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

It looks like the Weak Events or more specifically `WeakEventManager` or `IWeakEventListener` are not available in .Net Core as they are part of **WindowsBase** assembly.

Are there an alternatives to this feature?

Events are often a source of memory leaks in applications and weak references are a great way of dealing with this issue.

I couldn't find any information on this topic in stackoverflow

Comment: Use `WeakReference` directly.

Comment: @SLaks could you kindly demonstrate and example using WeakReference or point me to an example, either way I would make your answer the correct answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The library [Nito.Mvvm.Core](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Core) has a [`WeakCanExecuteChagned`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Core/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Core/WeakCanExecuteChanged.cs) class that does weak events using the command class you could use as a starting point for writing your manager backed by a `WeakCollection<EventHandler>`.

Here is a simple example using a custom class with a event named `Foo` that takes in a `FooEventArgs` object.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly WeakCollection<EventHandler<FooEventArgs>> _foo = new WeakCollection<EventHandler<FooEventArgs>>();

    public event EventHandler<FooEventArgs> Foo
    {
        add
        {
            lock (_foo)
            {
                _foo.Add(value);
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            lock (_foo)
            {
                _foo.Remove(value);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnFoo(FooEventArgs args)
    {
        lock (_foo)
        {
            foreach (var foo in _foo.GetLiveItems())
            {
                foo(this, args);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My library [System.Waf.Core](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf) provides a WeakEvent implementation that can be used as an alternative to the `WeakEventManager`.

**Example** for INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged:

```
public class Publisher : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}

public class Subscriber
{
    public void Init(Publisher publisher)
    {
        // Instead of publisher.PropertyChanged += Handler; use the following statement:
        WeakEvent.PropertyChanged.Add(publisher, Handler)        
    }

    public void Handler(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) { }
}
```

More details can be found on this Wiki page [Weak Event](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/Weak-Event).